# js popup is not showing html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created this test page [strutmymutt.com/rescues/test](http://strutmymutt.com/rescues/test) for sorting out 2 things.
First, when you click on "testing the html in js popup", popup is not missing the html part. This is the content I put for popup.

```
$a="Please add the dog first to make status updated, upload videos and photos or select the default dog.<br /><br /><a href='" . Phpfox::getLib('url')->makeUrl('dogs.add') . "'>Add  a Dog</a><br />";
```

2nd issue, I need to put footer at some fixed height if page content is shorter and for longer page, footer is fine.

Comment: popup is **not missing** the html part??? and I need to put footer at some fixed height if page content is shorter and for longer page??? Be specific

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** please provide the surrounding JavaScript to clarify that you don't mean you are using alert vs. some function from a framework.

Javascript alert doesn't typically support html tags.  Use a hidden div and jquery.toggle or .show() / .hide() to manage it.  That way you can display html in your popup.

**Edit:** Bootstrap popups **do** support html, so showing your surrounding code in a more thorough example will be a good way to enable others to help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your HTML tags are stripped away. Make sure that your $a variable is passed as it is to your popup and that it's not modified by stip_tags($a) or similar.

2nd: 
have a look at "sticky footer", this should solve your problem: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why still using js to create popup.. I think you have to use CSS3 tricks to create popup.. Like this : [Example CSS3 Popup](http://demo.syakirurohman.net/lab/css-popup).. You can create something like this by follow the tutorial [here](http://www.syakirurohman.net/en/2015/01/create-popup-without-javascript-jquery.html)